# PHP Regex - Finding two consecutive words with unknown number of spaces (" ") between them

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to create a PHP REGEX that will match if two words appear next to each other with ANY number of spaces between them.

For example, match "Daniel   Baylis" (3 spaces between 'Daniel' and 'Baylis').  I tried with this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
"/DANIEL[ ]{1,5}BAYLIS/" (this was to check up to 5 spaces which the most I expect in the data)
```

and

```
"/DANIEL[ ]{*}BAYLIS/"
```

I need to extract names from within larger bodies of text and names can appear anywhere within that text.  User input error is what creates the multiple spaces.

Thanks all! - Dan

Comment: You could also just replace the obsolete whitespaces first and afterward match for it, which should be easier ;)

Comment: `DANIEL[ ]{1,5}BAYLIS` this looks good, why didn't work?

Comment: @Kent I'm guessing case is the issue... ;)

Comment: I actually used /DANIEL[ ]{1,5}BAYLIS/i in my script though I didn't post in the example, but it wasn't getting the match. @Kent - do you think this should worked too?

Comment: i tested with `grep -i`, it worked. what i tried was ` echo "Daniel   BAYLIS"|grep -iP "Daniel[ ]{1,5}Baylis"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/DANIEL[ ]+BAYLIS/` should do... `+` will glob one or more occurence of the previous character(-class), in this case, litteral space.

Also, assuming you want to match regardless of the case, you'll need to adjust your regex to be case-insensitive, which I'm not sure how to do in PHP (it depends on which flavor of regex you use... Long time since I last touched that...)

Comment: That would be the `/i` modifier. It's also a good idea to use word boundaries here, and of course the brackets aren't necessary. `/\bDANIEL +BAYLIS\b/i` should do.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I was thinking about the `/i`, but from the top of my head there was a `pregi_`-namespaced set of methods in PHP that efficiently handled case-insensitive regexes without having to add the `/i`... But it's been ages as I said... Brackets are only there for clarity's sake. And word boundary is nice indeed, but the problem statement doesn't require them per my understanding :)

Comment: I just used the /i modifier with the preg_replace function

Comment: Worth noting is usage of `\s` for matching any form of whitespace (tabs, spaces, non-breaking spaces, newlines, etc).  May come in handy.
Also, for reference, `+` works the same as `{1,}` (one or more, no upper bounds) and `*` works the same as `{0,}` (zero or more, no upper bounds).